# how to decrement mutithreaded using fetch_sub and atomic_thread_fence?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, stdatomic

We have a member method (bool try()) which is supposed to be thread-safe which decrements the variable m_count if it is greater than 0 and we try to avoid mutexes and instead use fetch_sub and atomic_thread_fence.

```
struct Test {
  bool try() {
    if (m_count<1)
        return false;
    int count = m_count.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
    return true;
  }
  Test():m_count(1) {}
private:
  std::atomic<int> m_count;
}
```

We want to ensure that m_count never becomes less than 0 and that try returns true if m_count is decremented. Above two threads can decrement m_count from 1 to -1 and that is not acceptable.

Comment: Why do you have a relaxed operation and then a memory fence? Why not use the wanted memory order directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a gap between the load `if (m_count<1)` and the call to `fetch_sub()`.

Say `m_count == 1` and a thread executes the load and proceeds, but before it executes `fetch_sub()`, a second thread executes the load and gets the same value (`1`). Now both threads will execute `fetch_sub()` and `m_count` becomes `-1`.

To eliminate this gap, you can combine the compare and the modification into a single atomic compare-and-swap (CAS) operation, like this:

```
bool do_try() {
  bool modified=false;
  int current = m_count.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
  do {
    if (current == 0)
      break;
    assert(current > 0);

  } while (!(modified = m_count.compare_exchange_weak(current, current-1, std::memory_order_relaxed)));

  std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
  return modified;
}
```

Now `m_count` cannot become `-1`.

If `compare_exchange()` returns `false`, it updates its first argument with the latest value, so you do not have to call `load()` again.

Comment: Could this use `memory_order_acquire` on `compare_exchange_weak` and drop `atomic_thread_fence` completely?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Yes, but it's a pessimization in case you also have to use it on the `load` (it may lead to 2 fence instructions on weak platforms)

Comment: Why would  `load` need to use `memory_order_acquire`?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin That depends on what the code that's calling this looks like.